# <Select Multiple> options not highlighted from sql query

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to display the content of an imploded field as a multiple select but only the first required option is being marked as selected. 
I have tested this with checkboxes and it is working fine but I can't get it to work with a multiple select.
I have 2 tables - The first is the list of countries (CountryCode & Country) and the second is all of the information for a product with the Countries imploded into a field called COO.
If I print the array the countries that I need to have highlighted are displayed but not being selected.[Image attached is the results that are currently being produced. The first 5 countries should be highlighted but only the first is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbOLG.png)
Please go easy - I'm still trying to figure all this out!
Thanks

```
   <?php 
include('../config.php');
$Baseid=$_REQUEST['id'];
?>
<?php
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductBaseList WHERE Baseid='$Baseid'";
$supname = $row["SupplierName"];
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<form method=post action=opt3amend2.php><input type=hidden name=Baseid value=$Baseid><table width=700 border=0 cellspacing=10 cellpadding=10>";
            echo "<tr>";
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                            $Country_array = explode(',',$row['COO']);
                 ?>

                                    <select multiple name=COO[] size=10>

        <?
                $query2="SELECT * FROM Countries ORDER BY Country" ;
                $result2=mysqli_query($link,$query2);
             $num =  mysqli_num_rows($result2);
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2 ,MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ){

                 //echo $row['Country']; 

            ?>
                                        <option  value="<?php echo $row['Country'];?>" <?php if(in_array($row['Country'], $Country_array)) echo 'selected';?> ><?php echo  $row ['Country']; ?></option>

                                                             <?php } 
                                        }
        echo "<tr><td colspan=2 align=right><input type='reset' name='Reset'><input type='Submit' name='Amend' value='Amend'></td></tr></table></form>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "<br>$sql 1. No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
//mysqli_close($link);


?>
```

Comment: Please check the explode section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of problems.

1. `$row` is used as a result for both the queries.

   ```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ...

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2 ,MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ){ ... }
   ```

   Make the result variable unique.
2. `in_array` performs case sensitive search. Also, if there is a space before or after country name, it won't match. Add cleaning methods as followsm

   ```
   $Country_array = explode(',',$row['COO']);
   // make it lower case and trim values of array
   $Country_array = array_map('trim', array_map('strtolower', $Country_array));
   ```

   Then inside second `while` loop, do the same for individual country,

   ```
   $countryCompare = trim(strtolower($row['Country']));

   <?php if(in_array($countryCompare, $Country_array)) echo 'selected';?>
   ```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now.